# VMWare Network Setup

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I am looking to setup my **VMware guest** to be able to connect directly to a network through my host.
I have my host setup to have LAN/WAN switching disabled so that I can be online (internet) via WiFi but also plugged into a private network via hardwire.

Currently, I have **VMware** setup as **"NAT"** but I am looking for different performance.
For example: I have manually configured my host LAN IP to be `192.168.1.125` and it translates inside of my guest to `192.168.74.131`

This works OK for what I need, however, I need to be able to set my host up and guest up such that the IP inside the guest also resides directly on the `192.168.1.xxx` network.
I had a custom **VMnet** driver someone at work help me setup, however, I cannot get it to function as it once did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use bridged networking?  If you need the guest to be able to connect to both networks on your host, you could give the VM two network adapters and set each to use a VMnet that bridges to one of your host's adapters.

Comment: I did not know this was possible. Worked like a charm. Thank you.